# How to print the transpose of a 2d vector with different number of columns?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working with some 2d vectors and I'm trying to print the transpose of the vector.

The sub vectors are not the same size and whenever there is a space on a column I am getting an `out of range` error. So I'm looking for a solution to omit the missing parts and instead, print them as spaces.

So far I have this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tbl =
    {
       {4},
       {4, 2},
       {4, 2, 7},
       {4, 2, 7},
       {4, 2, 7, 5}
    };


    size_t j = 0;
    int emp = 0;

    // emp help avoiding emtpy spaces
    while (j < 4)
    {
        unsigned int emptySpaces = 0;
        for (size_t i = emp; i < tbl.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << tbl[i][j] << "  ";
            if (i <= j)
            {
                emp += 1;
            }
        }
        j++;
        std::cout << "\n\n";

        // the empty spaces
        while (emptySpaces < j)
        {
            std::cout << "   ";
            emptySpaces++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for vector with size 4 would look like this:

```
4  4  4  4  4 
   2  2  2  2
      7  7  7
            5
```

It works for vectors with 3 columns but when I try it with 4 it won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing some examples of input and expected output will also be very helpful.

Comment: Your program is still not reproducible. It looks like you're missing `main`?

Comment: "Reverse the vector's rows with columns and print them" -- do you mean transposing? e.g. `a[i][j]` becomes `a[j][i]`? if so, how could you possibly implement this if the sub-vectors aren't the same size?

Comment: You may want to create a `int main()` that fills the array without any user input so that the code can be easily tested

Comment: have a look at the examples

Comment: What you are doing is called a "transpose" in linear algebra, but the fundamental problem is how do you intend to account for the "space" before your numbers after the transpose? You will need some way to indicate the absence of a value at the start of your vector. If that doesn't matter, then it's just a case of creating a `new_vec[i][j]` from the values of `old_vec[j][i]` (if they exist)

Comment: Actually, disregard that problem. The title was a little misleading... The title makes it sound like you're trying to swap elements in the vector, but the edited question is just about printing. That's not so bad.

Comment: Yeah, I m just trying to print them like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to concentrate on the task at hand. You want to print a matrix. If an entry of the matrix does not exist, you want to print a space character.

Printing the matrix is usually done with two nested loops:

```
for(int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        ...
```

Checking if an element exists can be done using the vector length:

```
if(row < tbl[col].size())
    // element exists
```

Putting all together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tbl =
    {
       {4},
       {4, 2},
       {4, 2, 7},
       {4, 2, 7},
       {4, 2, 7, 5},
    };


    size_t cols = tbl.size();

    // find the number of rows
    size_t rows = 0;
    for (auto& col : tbl)
        if (col.size() > rows)
            rows = col.size();

    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            // check if the element exists
            if (row < tbl[col].size())
                // it exists, print it
                std::cout << tbl[col][row];
            else
                // it does not exist, print a space
                std::cout << " ";

            // separating space
            std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```